# OpenCV, tensorflow or tesseract OCR codes about finding duplicate numbers in an image and marking them

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, ocr, tesseract

I'm looking for a OpenCV, tensorflow or tesseract OCR codes about finding duplicate numbers in an image and marking them. For example I have numbers listed from 1 to 99 in an image and i dont want any number to repeat more than once, but in my paperworks there are some repetitions (i.e two "65" randomly in the paper like 05 23 65 86 65 12 33 21 etc.) and i want to discard those repeated paperworks. In real life it is a huge struggle to read them all can you guide me? I want to make an app for mobile phone with python(thats only language im familiar with) to use that with camera for faster solution is it possible? Or is there an existing program like this scans and finds dublicate numbers/texts in real life image/text? Please God help me I'm so much in a mess...

Comment: be specific and add your own attempts first. this question you should google first and go through a few blogs.

Comment: Using tesseract should be enough for this problem.

Comment: I've tried everything, but literally there is nothing as far as I've checked. Specification is I'm looking for a way to make a program to identify two same numbers with phone camera.